# angular js data table fix header scroll bar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using AngularJS DataTable with `fixheader` option. below plugin using as a table
[plugin](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/welcome)

when using the fix header option, it's working well. but there is an alignment issue in my table.
Please check the attached image.
[image]

how I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the `<th>` initialize your columns and then check the `colspan` to match the number of columns you have.